# "async/await is not yet supported in Client Components" error on reload, but works if routed to the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am having a pretty interesting error. I keep getting the clasic Nextjs 13 "Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components." This error occurs when I reload or fast refresh (in dev) while on the page.

But when I am routed to the page using Nextjs' <Link />, the error doesn't pop up and everything works as intended.

This is where it get's interesting: I have the exact same code on a different page, but everything works normal on that other page.

I saw that the problem came from a certain hook (zustand store). I put working code in the file that uses that hook and it still failed.

Here is the code:

./cpx/page.tsx

```
"use client";
import Container from "@/components/Container";
import OfferWall from "@/components/Offerwall";
import { useProfile } from "@/hooks/useProfile";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CpxPage = () => {
  const { profile } = useProfile();

  const secure_hash = "...";

  const url = `https://offers.cpx-research.com/index.php?app_id=8755&secure_hash=${secure_hash}&ext_user_id=${profile?.userid}`;

  return (
    <Container>
      <OfferWall iframe={url} title="Cpx Offerwall" />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CpxPage;
```

./components/Offerwall.tsx

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { useProfile } from "@/hooks/useProfile";

const OfferWall = ({ iframe, title }: { iframe: string; title: string }) => {
  // console.log(iframe);

  return (
    <div className="items-center h-full pb-12">
      <div className="flex justify-between w-full items-center my-4">
        <Link href={"/app/earn"}>
          <Button>Back</Button>
        </Link>
        <p className="text-2xl font-semibold">{title}</p>
        <Button>Help</Button>
      </div>

      <iframe
        src={iframe}
        title={title}
        className="w-full h-[650px] border-[3px] border-primary shadow-md rounded-md"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default OfferWall;
```

./hooks/useProfile.tsx

```
import { SavedProfile } from "@/lib/server-functions/utils/types";
import { create } from "zustand";

//Profile State

interface ProfileState {
  profile: SavedProfile | null;
  setProfile: (profile: SavedProfile) => void;
}

export const useProfile = create<ProfileState>()((set) => ({
  profile: null,
  setProfile: (profile: SavedProfile) => set({ profile }),
}));
```

If you have any idea why this is happening, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that you use the `useProfile` in a server component when you are on the other page. Thus it is probably created then and not when you refresh on a client component page.

Comment: @grekier I just realized that one of the containers was pulling information for useProfile() while it wasn't even in the scope. Your comment actually helped me realize the mistake, thanks!